# Labeling a dataframe based on unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, unique

I have the following dataframe:

```
x=df[['PROJECT','ID']] 
print(x)



        PROJECT       ID
0           1         10
1           1         32
2           1         32
3           1          9
4           1         32
5           1         10
6           2         10
7           2         33
8           2         54
9           2          9
10          2         31
11          2         10
12          3         10
13          3         54
14          3         53
15          3         11
16          3         33
17          3         54
```

I want to add a third column titled 'Unique' with values 'Yes' or 'No'. If the value of an index in the column with label 'ID' is present more than once AND they have the same value for 'PROJECT', than the value must be attributed a 'No', otherwise 'Yes'. So the outcome I'd like to have would look like:

```
         PROJECT       ID     Unique
0           1         10      No
1           1         32      No
2           1         32      No
3           1          9      Yes
4           1         32      No
5           1         10      No
6           2         10      No
7           2         33      Yes
8           2         54      Yes
9           2          9      Yes
10          2         31      Yes
11          2         10      No
12          3         10      Yes
13          3         54      No
14          3         53      Yes
15          3         11      Yes
16          3         33      Yes
17          3         54      No
```

You basically have to see rows with the same PROJECT value as a subset for which you have to determine the uniqueness of the corresponding ID values. Rows with different values for 'PROJECT' have no connection. I tried several things with combining either `np.groupby` , `np.isin` or `np.unique` with some sort of loop but it hasn't worked yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with the `subset` parameter set to only consider certain columns. Then we can convert the boolean values to `'Yes'`/`'No'` with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Unique'] = np.where(
    df.duplicated(subset=['PROJECT', 'ID'], keep=False), 'No', 'Yes'
)
```

`df`:

```
    PROJECT  ID Unique
0         1  10     No
1         1  32     No
2         1  32     No
3         1   9    Yes
4         1  32     No
5         1  10     No
6         2  10     No
7         2  33    Yes
8         2  54    Yes
9         2   9    Yes
10        2  31    Yes
11        2  10     No
12        3  10    Yes
13        3  54     No
14        3  53    Yes
15        3  11    Yes
16        3  33    Yes
17        3  54     No
```

---

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'PROJECT': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'ID': [10, 32, 32, 9, 32, 10, 10, 33, 54, 9, 31, 10, 10, 54, 53, 11, 33, 54]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by 'Project' and for each group mark the 'ID' duplicates with True using [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html). Then map the True values (i.e. duplicates) to 'No', and False to 'Yes' using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html?highlight=map#pandas.Series.map).

```
df['Unique'] = (
    df.groupby('PROJECT')['ID']
      .apply(lambda g: g.duplicated(keep=False))
      .map({True:'No', False:'Yes'})
)

>>> df

    PROJECT  ID Unique
0         1  10     No
1         1  32     No
2         1  32     No
3         1   9    Yes
4         1  32     No
5         1  10     No
6         2  10     No
7         2  33    Yes
8         2  54    Yes
9         2   9    Yes
10        2  31    Yes
11        2  10     No
12        3  10    Yes
13        3  54     No
14        3  53    Yes
15        3  11    Yes
16        3  33    Yes
17        3  54     No
```

Comment: `.duplicated` is so genius...

Comment: @user17242583 Thanks ;) I don't why there is no `SeriesGroupBy.duplicated` or `DataFrameGroupBy.duplicated`though...

Comment: @HarryPlotter because there doesn't need to be. `subset` already handles this... `df['Unique'] = np.where(df.duplicated(subset=['PROJECT', 'ID'], keep=False), 'No', 'Yes')`

Comment: @HenryEcker oh of course! I totally forgot about it, silly me... Once again I'm overcomplicating it ;) Make it an answer. Definitely better than mine!

Comment: It happens. I frequently overcomplicate things. That's one of the things I like about SO is that people remind me when I do.